# Can a wave exist within a black hole?

Tags: waves, black-holes

Can a wave exist within a black hole?  A wave implies motion (amplitude and frequency) but motion can not occur without the passage of time.  A wave also implies wavelength that cannot occur because gravity does not allow for any outward motion.  Therefore, can a wave even exist inside a black hole?

In this forum we always speak of relative time and motion.  But is there a relative timeframe if time is completely stopped?  Can we speak of the frame of reference of being within a black hole if time does not move at all?

Comment: Yes, every mass according to Einstein emits gravitational waves, including black holes. There's no restriction that gravitational waves must propagate only outwards from black hole, they can be emitted also inwards, inside black hole.

Comment: You should clarify what type of a black hole you are asking about, a real collapsed star or a mathematical abstraction like the Schwarzschild solution that cannot exist in reality. Real collapsars are empty with no possible motion inside for the exact reasons you stated. See this for details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310040/ - Time does exist in hypothetical Schwarzschild black holes for a short duration, so motion is possible there before time ends, but these black holes don't exist in reality. Without stating, which black holes you have in mind, your question is unclear.

Comment: @safesphere   I'm thinking of a real black hole.

Comment: @safesphere  can you comment on the second paragraph of my OP. Can we speak of a frame of reference if time does not move at all?  Or does it simply move into the realm of dividing by 0, so infinity?

Comment: A frame is a 4D coordinate system measuring space and time of a physical object (e.g. observer). Assuming no movement in time inside a collapsar: (1) all coordinate systems become 3D (space only) and (2) there are no physical objects (energy is zero) to attach a coordinate system to one to call it a "frame". In this sense there are no frames without time, although you still can have coordinate systems to measure distances between points in empty space just like on a clean sheet of paper. However, such a measurement is only hypothetical, as it can be done neither on the inside nor from outside.

Comment: "Dividing by zero" refers to light. No physical coordinate system can be defined at the speed of light at all. 4D coordinates become null: no time, no space, nothing to measure, no material object to refer to. A very different case from a collapsar black hole where coordinates still exist for space without time and where the speed of light is zero. See the link above for more details.

Comment: @safesphere  If time has stopped inside the event horizon, can objects that fall past the event horizon continue to fall all the way into the singularity in the centre of the black hole?

Comment: A black hole solution consists of two regions, outside and inside. With no big charge or fast rotation, the outside region is always normal Schwarzschild (just like around the Earth). The inside region depends on your choice of initial conditions and other things: (1) Schwarzschild - time inside is not stopped and there is a singularity; (2) Oppenheimer-Snyder and some others - similar to the previous; (3) a flat space with time stopped (what you seem to be asking about) - there is no matter inside and no singularity, all matter is at the horizon, nothing can fall through the horizon.

Comment: The latter option is detailed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310040/metric-of-spacetime-with-zero-speed-of-light

Comment: @safesphere  Under your item 3, flat space, wouldn't the original star form a singularity in the centre of the black hole, and just everything that follows stopped at the horizon?   Is there a name for this particular theory that I can research?

Answer (score 4):

This is an underspecified question as such but still it can be answered by deconstructing the question by pointing out conceptual misunderstandings I guess. So I'll give it a go.

1. Wave doesn't imply motion. Only mechanical waves imply motion. Electromagnetic waves are also waves and there is no motion associated with it. It simply consists of oscillations of electric and magnetic fields. However, you're right that you need a notion of time to have a notion of wave (although, this would be true of any physically meaningful notion, a physics without time is something not much imaginable)
2. Time doesn't cease to exist in a black hole (except at singularity where we don't know what happens). Time certainly exists inside a blackhole. In fact, according to general relativity, you won't even notice that you crossed the horizon if you're falling into a large enough black hole.
3. Yes, if you use the coordinates of an observer sitting at the asymptomatic infinity, it'd look like the time stops as you approach horizon and the metric blows up at the horizon. However, this is just a pathology of a bad coordinate system as has been well understood for a long time. If you choose a good set of coordinates such as the Kruskel coordinates, you see that nothing catastrophic happens at the horizon and an infalling observer wouldn't even notice that they have crossed the horizon as I mentioned.
4. Finally, electromagnetic waves can obviously exist inside the blackhole. No electromagnetic wave can come outside of the blackhole but radiation can certainly fall into blackhole. For example, see, the ingoing Vaidya metric which is a blackhole solution with radiation falling into the blackhole.

Comment: Thankyou. Can you please clarify, 1. if things are falling into a black hole at speed c, how can time exist? Is it not dilated to a full stop?   2.  can you speak of the wave length question?  Would not any wave attempting to leave the black hold just pile up on itself and have zero wave length?  3.  Yes, you would not notice if you fell into a black hole, but if time has stopped, you would never know that it has stopped for you too.  You wouldn't even have time to think a single thought?

Comment: @foolishmuse 1. There is no valid proper frame of something moving at the speed of light. So you're not allowed to talk about the frame of reference of light. This is a simple fact from special relativity having nothing to do with horizons or black holes. 2. As I said, no wave or particle or anything for that matter leave black holes but they can absolutely fall into it. [...]

Comment: [...] 3. When I say you wouldn't notice if you fell into a black holes, I meant you would be perfectly conscious with your clock ticking just fine and you wouldn't notice. Not because time stops and you stop thinking but because nothing special happens at horizon.

Comment: Clarification: when I say nothing special happens at horizon, that's a statement in general relativity. If you include quantum mechanics, a lot of controversial stuff might or might not happen at horizon depending on who has the good fortune of winning those sweet physics bets. ;) But if something special does happen at horizon, equivalence principle would have to be sacrificed so I'd personally bet otherwise.

Comment: @safesphere I already mentioned like two times that I'm limiting my answer to general relativity for it is not exactly settled how OP's questions regarding the horizon would be answered in quantum mechanics. Within general relativity, where is this non-outdated knowledge that would contradict the simple statement that you'd fall through the horizon of a blackhole smoothly?

Comment: I meant the classical GR. Knowledge is plenty once you get out of the mainstream propaganda bubble. Just one example, see the black hole theorem here on p. 43: https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/preprints/ni14098.pdf - but even intuitively (1) the equivalence principle is local, holds in a small area and doesn’t apply across the global horizon; (2) nothing crosses the horizon in any external frame: if you fall feet forward, you don’t see your feet crossing until your eyes reach the horizon; (3) the proper time ends at the horizon; (4) Kruskal coordinates don’t remove the horizon singularity, etc,

Comment: @safesphere OK, and who exactly is spreading this "propaganda"? What is their motive? Is there a big Kruskal coordinates lobby bribing the physics departments? 1. Sure, and that's why I said a big enough black hole so that a human would constitute a local enough system. 4. There is no singularity at the horizon, to begin with. All coordinate independent things such as the Ricci scalar and the Kretschmann scalar are finite at the horizon. 2,3. I don't see why you'd like to study horizons using some coordinate system that manifestly can't do that. Why not use a coordinate system that can do that

Comment: Furthermore, all your arguments are for the unphysical empty Schwarzschild black hole. No real physical process can generate the Schwarzschild spacetime inside, because in a real collapse this spacetime is already defined as non-Schwarzschild forever: the entire spacetime manifold region inside. See the link in my comment under the question. The spacetime inside a black hole is either Schwarzschild forever or non-Schwarzschild forever. Both at the same time cannot coexist without unphysical extra dimensions or covering spaces. A collapsing star cannot produce a trapping horizon or singularity.

Comment: “*Is there a big Kruskal coordinates lobby bribing the physics departments?*” - LOL! Not under this name, but essentially yes. You keep throwing naive arguments. Look at the theorem. No mathematically valid coordinate transformation can remove the horizon singularity. Plus the Kruskal coordinates don’t represent spacetime of any physical observer and thus are unphysical. Sadly this thread has reached the allowed limit. I’d love to help, but this site prohibits discussions. Good luck!

Comment: My apologies, here is the correct link to overlapping spaces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513195/ - You can clearly see that for **any** $r$ and $t$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ spacetime inside is either Schwarzschild or non-Schwarzschild, e.g. Minkowski in case of a hollow shell. It obviously cannot be both. Also a human is never "local" at the horizon, because metric components diverge there along with the potential and acceleration. "Small" means much smaller than the distance to the horizon. The equivalence principle is not based on the curvature scalars. They are irrelevant.